# React Webpack Production errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to setup a webpack (1.13.3) config for a React (15.3.2) app, and I want the production version of React in my production build. I'm on Windows.

I'm using this (which is everywhere online when you search):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})
```

However, as soon as I add this and run `webpack` (CLI) I get slapped round the face with many many errors.

I get a whole bunch of these **warnings**:

> WARNING in ./~/fbjs/lib/partitionObject.js.flow
>   Module parse failed: C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\fbjs\lib[ SOME FILE NAME HERE].flow Unexpected token (18:24)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

...and a bunch of these **errors**:

> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/TextInputState' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js 17:21-63

I'm not using React Native, I wouldn't know how.

I'm also using `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` in my `webpack.config.production.js` file.

When I remove the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` bit the build works, but includes the development version of React and I get warnings in the console:

> Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster.

What are these webpack errors all about..? How do I get a production build of React which is also minified..?

**UPDATE**

Full webpack config requested. I've setup a test app for this, with minimum config and the warnings and errors are still showing:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./webpack.config.production.js') : require('./webpack.config.development.js')
```

webpack.config.base.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle': './client/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.development.js

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.base')
module.exports = config
```

webpack.config.production.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

var config = require('./webpack.config.base')

config.plugins = [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    include: /\.js$/,
    compress: { warnings: false }
  })
]

module.exports = config
```

The test app I'm using only has the following installed:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "react": "^15.3.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
  "webpack": "^1.13.3"
}
```

/client/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Hello from '../components/Hello'
ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('page'))
```

/components/Hello.js

```
import React from 'react'
const Hello = props => <p>Hello world...</p>
export default Hello
```

**Asked again in a separate question, but with the full error list, and from a React Native view, because the errors contain references to React Native, even though I'm not trying to use it:**

[Webpack in production: Why React Native errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469980/webpack-in-production-why-react-native-errors)

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right. Are you sure you don't use an external library that has a dependency on react-native somewhere? That seems to be the issue here. Can you post your full webpack config?

Comment: I've just updated my question with the webpack config files. It works, no warnings or errors, without the `webpack.ProvidePlugin`. With the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` all the errors show again.

Comment: Just added my `dependencies` lists too...

Comment: Nothing seems to be incorrect here... You are just using simple `import React from 'react'`, right? No weird imports?

Comment: Nothing weird - Just added the contents of the `index.js` that webpack points to. I do a server render first, but that shouldn't effect what webpack is doing.

Comment: Well, I really don't get it in that case. Absolutely nothing looks wrong, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: [Webpack in production: Why React Native errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469980/webpack-in-production-why-react-native-errors) by Aruna Herath.

I should be using `DefinePlugin` not `ProvidePlugin`.