# Webpack: -p vs NODE_ENV=production vs process.env.NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm having [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464929/react-webpack-production-errors) with webpack in production and I'm getting confused with the different ways of running webpack in the production environment (I'm using Windows).

Can someone explain the difference between these:

One: CLI

- `webpack -p`

Two: CLI

- `SET NODE_ENV=production`
- `webpack`

Three: webpack.config.js

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})
```

I'm using React and need to build a production version which is both minified and includes the production version of React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SET NODE_ENV=production` sets NODE_ENV environment variable to "production" on the server. The machine that compiles and bundles your javascript source files. So it can for example select a different webpack config file for production.

But this enviroment variable has no effect when this javascript code actually runs. Because the javascript code will run on a browser in a different machine.

The [providePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) helps to set NODE_ENV variable in the browser. Where your javascript actually runs. Actually what it really does is replacing occurences of `process.env.NODE_ENV` with `"production"` rather than setting a variable. But effects are same.

**EDIT**: It's actually [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) that should be used for this purpose.

Weback `-p` advertises to doing the second of above but seems to have [some issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2537).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#the-automatic-way) setting `webpack -p` performs following

- Minification using UglifyJSPlugin
- Runs the LoaderOptionsPlugin
- **Sets the Node environment variable**

So instead of doing:

```
"scripts": {
  "dist": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
  "start": "webpack"
}
```

You can just specify

```
"scripts": {
  "dist": "webpack -p",
  "start": "webpack"
}
```