# Webpack in production: Why React Native errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I have a test app with the following installed:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "react": "^15.3.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
  "webpack": "^1.13.3"
}
```

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle': './client/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why do I get these **React Native** related errors..?? I'm not trying to use React Native!

(When I remove `webpack.ProvidePlugin()` the errors go away, but I need the production build of React).

> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/TextInputState' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js 17:21-63
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin.js 18:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBaseComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBaseComponent.js 22:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBaseComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/deepFreezeAndThrowOnMutationInDev' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBaseComponent.js 24:40-101
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeAttributePayload.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/deepDiffer' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeAttributePayload.js 16:17-55
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeAttributePayload.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/flattenStyle' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeAttributePayload.js 17:19-59
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBridgeEventPlugin.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeBridgeEventPlugin.js 20:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDOMIDOperations.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDOMIDOperations.js 15:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js 23:0-57
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/RCTEventEmitter' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js 27:22-65
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/View' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeDefaultInjection.js 79:15-47
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeGlobalResponderHandler.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeGlobalResponderHandler.js 13:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeMount.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeMount.js 21:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeTextComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-native/lib/UIManager' in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeTextComponent.js 19:16-53
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFiber.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./ReactFiberReconciler in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFiber.js 15:27-60
>
> ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactNoop.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./ReactFiberReconciler in C:\node\sandbox\react-webpack\node_modules\react\lib
>    @ ./~/react/lib/ReactNoop.js 22:27-60

Comment: Try completely removing node_modules folder and installing deps from a clean state again. If you could push your test app to Github I am happy to clone it and try it out myself.

Comment: That's very kind of you:  https://github.com/stephen-last/react-webpack-test

Comment: Wait. Shouldn't you be using `DefinePlugin` instead of `ProvidePlugin`? I am using `DefinePlugin` in my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) Instead of ProvidePlugin. That's the plugin used for this use case.

I don't understand what triggered those errors though. I think `react` does contain some code that are specific to `react-native`.

Comment: Brilliant - that was it... It works now... Nobody spotted that before, in two stack questions. Thank you!